# Increment date in row by 1 day each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In SQL I have an output table like the following:

`MemNo | PipNomDt                 | PIPStrtDt
1739  |  2007-03-31 00:00:00.000 |  2009-02-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2007-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2008-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2009-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  NULL                    |  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000`

I need to update this table so that when the first row of Date1 is populated, all of the rows below are populated with an increment of 1 day so it would appear as the following.

`MemNo | PipNomDt                 | PIPStrtDt
1739  |  2007-03-31 00:00:00.000 |  2009-02-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 |  2007-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-02 00:00:00.000 |  2008-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-03 00:00:00.000 |  2009-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-04 00:00:00.000 |  2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-05 00:00:00.000 |  2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-06 00:00:00.000 |  2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
1739  |  2007-04-07 00:00:00.000 |  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000`

I did try the following code but I'm not really sure how to actually go about doing this

```
            UPDATE  pip
            SET     PIPNomDt = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1,
                                       ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                n.PIPNomDt
                                         FROM   dbo.wtPIPNomDt_List n ,
                                                dbo.wtPIPStrtDt_List s
                                         WHERE  n.RowID = s.RowID
                                       ))
            FROM    dbo.htPensionInputPeriod pip
                    JOIN ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MemNo ) rn ,
                                    MemNo
                           FROM     dbo.htPensionInputPeriod
                         ) t2_numbered ON t2_numbered.MemNo = @MemNo
```

Comment: What defines the "first" row? Do you have any type of unique key that can be used to order your rows?

Comment: This comes from the UI, but if the top row is populated, we then want to fill the rest.

Comment: How is the UI ordering the rows? Why did it put any particular row on top? Relational theory forbids any type of implicit order on a set of data...it has to be explicitly defined in the query.

Comment: This is irrelevant, the order of the rows has been signed off and is coming out correctly, I just want to know how to update the proceeding rows with the first date with the day incremented by one.

Comment: Seems to me it's ordered by `PIPStrtDt`, so you could use that in the `ROW_NUMBER` function?

Comment: Philip, it IS relevant. Why else would you need `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MemNo )`? The issue is that since your `MemNo` column seems to contain duplicate values, SQL Server will _arbitrarily_ order these rows. A relational database is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @NickyvV ordered by Month then Year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, 
            Row_number() 
              OVER( 
                partition BY memno 
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN pipnomdt IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
              pipstrtdt) 
            AS 
               RN 
     FROM   table1
)
,cte_next AS 
(SELECT * 
     FROM   cte 
     WHERE  rn = 1 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT C1.memno, 
            dateadd(day,1,c1.pipnomdt), 
            c2.pipstrtdt, 
            c2.rn 
     FROM   cte_next c1 
            JOIN cte c2 
              ON c1.memno = c2.memno 
                 AND c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte_next
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb266/11/0)

Comment: I like the ordering in the `Row_number()`, however you could've formatted the answer a bit so that it would become more readable.. And i'm missing the new date column (PipNomDt) I believe?

Comment: @NickyvV Point taken, Thanks
 and I dont think column is missing

Comment: Thanks, and I see your `c1.pipnomdt + 1`, but I don't believe that's working for date(time) datatypes. You'll have to use `DATEADD` for that.

Comment: @NickyvV, Changed to dateadd. However question had a datetime datatype and +1 works well with datetime, I believe

Comment: You might wanny try February 28th+1 :)

Comment: It works
declare @datetime datetime='20120228';
select @datetime+1

Comment: Only tested that one? :) Please try `@datetime datetime='20130228'; select @datetime+1` then? >> Hmm.. sorry on that one, then SQLFiddle just doesn't work :D

Comment: I get 2013-03-01 00:00:00.000,what's the issue?

Comment: @NickyvV, SQLFiddle  works fine. You either remove the semicolon or change query terminator to "GO"

Comment: @SatheeshVariath thanks, this is implemented and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My following test was able to produce results similar to those you are looking for: I'm not sure if I've correctly understood the relationship between MemNo and RowID, but it should give you a start. I made the assumption that you only wanted to update values with a matching MemNo, in the order of RowID - you can change that if necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE pip
  (
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
MemNo INT NOT NULL,
Date1 DATETIME NULL
  )

INSERT INTO pip (MemNo, Date1) VALUES (1, '8/3/2013')
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)
INSERT INTO pip (MemNo) VALUES (1739)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER T_pip ON pip
    FOR UPDATE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    UPDATE pip2
    SET pip2.date1 = DATEADD(DAY, s.RowNum, inserted.Date1)
    FROM 
        inserted 
         INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT
                RowID,
                MemNo,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemNo ORDER BY RowID )     RowNum
            FROM pip
          ) s ON 
            inserted.RowID < s.RowID AND
            inserted.MemNo = s.MemNo
         INNER JOIN 
        pip pip2 ON 
            s.RowID = pip2.RowID


  END

GO

SELECT * FROM pip

UPDATE pip
SET Date1 = '3/31/2007' 
WHERE pip.RowID = 2

SELECT * FROM pip


-- DROP TABLE pip
```